Optimized way to replace a large list of dicts
Let's say I have a (large) list of (large) dicts, for instance:
my_list = [
    {
        "foo": "bar",
        "foobar": "barfoo",
        "something": 1,
        "useless_bool": True
    },
    {
        "foo": "rab",
        "foobar": "oofrab",
        "something": 1,
        "useless_str": "different_value"
    },
    ...
]

Where this list contains thousands of dicts, and where each dicts can have hundreds of keys. Also I have a Jinja template, for instance:
jinja_template = jinja2.Environment().from_string(
    "{{ foo }} - {{ foobar }} - {{ something }}"
)

For each dict in my list, I want add a new key containing the rendered Jinja template (using other existing keys), and remove all other keys. To end with something like:
[
    {
        "new_key": "bar - barfoo - 1"
    },
    {
        "new_key": "rab - oofrab - different_value"
    },
    ...
]

So far I made a (dumb) loop to do so:
import jinja2

new_message_template = jinja2.Environment().from_string("{{ foo }} - {{ foobar }} - {{ something }}")

for item in my_list:
    # Render the new value
    rendered_value = new_message_template.render(**item)
    # Remove all existing keys
    item.clear()
    # Set the new key/value
    item["new_key"] = rendered_value

This works.
But considering this list contains thousands of dicts, with each having hundreds of keys, is there a more optimized way to perform this operation, in term of performances and execution time ?

If you can, I think you should get rid of the whole dict, and just creating a new list of the strings. This way, you are not modifying the existing structure. This may improve performance. You could also look into numpy list operations.

Couple of things:

jinja2.Environment().from_string("{{ foo }} - {{ foobar }} - {{ something }}") this expression is currently getting ignored. I'm assuming this is supposed to be assigned to new_message_template

You are doing in place mutations on the dictionary. Why? Just create a new list of transformed dicts.

Jinja 2 template rendering is I/O bound making it a good candidate for thread based concurrency. Threading is good for I/O bound tasks because python threads run concurrently while waiting for I/O operations to complete. You can use ThreadPoolExecutor


import jinja2
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

new_message_template = jinja2.Environment().from_string("{{ foo }} - {{ foobar }} - {{ something }}")

def process_item(item):
    rendered_value = new_message_template.render(**item)
    return {"new_key": rendered_value}

def process_data(data):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = list(executor.map(process_item, data))
    return result

# Example data
my_list = [
    {"foo": "value1", "foobar": "value2", "something": "value3"},
    {"foo": "hello", "foobar": "world", "something": "!"}
]

new_list = process_data(my_list)

print(new_list)


Maybe "4. Use render(item) instead of render(**item)"?

Thx for this answer. 1: bad copy/paste on my side, sorry for this. 2: I was trying to avoid having 2 (big) variables, to avoid bad impact on the memory side. 3: that's an excellent idea to use threads here. But it seems slower: on a list with 10k items, this method with ThreadPoolExecutor took ~0.06sec to execute, while the code in my original post took ~0.03sec to execute.
I'm very surprised by this result, I thought using threads should speed up the execution
